# Call Subview function with MainView boolean

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, state

I am desperately trying the following:

I have a ForEach loop in the MainView that contains a different number of ListRowView.  This ListRowView contains a HStack with player.name and player.points and a TextField, where the player can write a number and it will be summed up or subtracted away.

In the ListRowView after pressing the "Calculate" button in the MainView the function updatePoints() should be called, but here I fail (I tried it with didSet and willSet). Does anyone here have an idea how best to implement this?

Thanks

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    //Binding
    @Binding var game : Game

    //for Changing the Points
    @State private var addingPoints : Bool = true
    @State private var invokeFunction : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            let players : [Player] = game.players
            
            NavigationView{
                
                VStack{
                    
                    List{
                        
                        Section(){
                            
                            ForEach(players, id: \.self){
                                player in
                                
                                ListRowView(invokeFunction: $invokeFunction, addingPoints: addingPoints, player: player)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            invokeFunction.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Calculate")
                            }
                        })
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

And here the (Subview) ListRowView, where the func updatePoints() should be called.

```
struct ListRowView: View {
    
    @Binding var invokeFunction : Bool 
    
    @State var addingPoints : Bool
    @State var player : Player
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack{
            
            Text("\(player.name)")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("\(player.points)")
            
            Spacer()
            
            
            //add or delete number from points
            Button(action: {
                addingPoints.toggle()
            }){
                if(addingPoints){
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(OwnColor.ownRed)
                }
            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            
            
            //added new points with own TextField
            TextField("0", text: $limitTextField.text)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            
        }
    }
    
    mutating func updatePoints(add: Bool) -> Void {
        var newPoints = 0
        
        if self.invokeFunction {
            if (limitTextField.text.isEmpty) {
                self.player.points += newPoints
            } else {
                newPoints = Int(limitTextField.text) ?? 0
                if (add) {
                    self.player.points += newPoints
                    print("Add \t Old points: \(player.points - newPoints) - New Points: \(player.points)")
                } else {
                    self.player.points -= newPoints
                    print("Sub \t Old points: \(player.points + newPoints) - New Points: \(player.points)")
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        invokeFunction.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

And here is also the Player struct

```
struct Player : Identifiable, Codable, Hashable{
    let id : UUID
    var name : String
    var points : Int
    
    var hashValue: Int {
        return name.hashValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `@State` in front of `var addingPoints` and `player`. Then you should be able to remove the `mutating`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainView` just use the @Binding with the game variable

```
var body: some View {
    
    //Remove this
    //let players : [Player] = game.players
    NavigationView{                
        VStack{   
            List{                        
                Section(){                            
                    ForEach($game.players, id: \.self){
                        player in
                        
                        ListRowView(invokeFunction: $invokeFunction, addingPoints: addingPoints, player: player)
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    calculateAllPlayers()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Calculate")
                    }
                })
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

This way the ForEach dinamically updates the players whenever the 'game' object gets modified within the `calculateAllPlayers` function you'll have something like this

```
func calculateAllPlayers(add: Bool) -> Void {

    for player in game.players {
        //do your calulations here modifying the 'player' object
    }
    
}
```

In your subview you can just remove the @State from the player variable and add the @Binding

EDIT: I'm adding another possibility here as the OP specified that he cannot access the data from the main view.

You could also add an .onChange(of) on the subview as so

```
HStack{
    
    Text("\(player.name)")
    //....
    
}
.onChange(of: invokeFunction) {
    if invokeFunction {
       //call your function
    }
}
```

The onChange is called every time the `of` state has changed

Comment: This doesn't work the way it should be, because I have several ListRowViews which should all work independent and i can't access that data from my main view - so the question i'm asking is: Is it possible that I change the Bool in the main view, so that the subview knows, when this Bool changed in the main view, it should call the func in the Subview

Comment: Yes sure you can do that too, I edited my question and added a different viable solution